# Copying a snapshot of a Canvas to a BufferedImage

Tags: java, network-programming, awt

I'm currently using a Canvas with an associated BufferStrategy. How can I copy the contents (image) of the Canvas and save it to a BufferedImage. So far I've only tried

```
BufferedImage image = ...
g = image.createGraphics();
canvas.printAll(g); //or paintAll
```

However, it appears that only a 'blank' (filled with the background color) screen is being drawn; I it's assume because that's the default behavior of `Canvas.paint()`. Is there as way for me to retrieve the image currently on screen (the last one shown with `BufferStrategy.show()`), or do I need to draw to a BufferedImage and copy the image to the BufferStrategy's graphics. It seems like that would/could be a big slow down; would it?

Why (because I know someone wants to ask): I already have a set of classes set up as a framework, using Canvas, for building games that can benefit from rapidly refreshing screens, and I'm looking to make an addon framework to have one of these canvases tied into a remote server, sending it's displayed image to other connected clients. (Along the lines of remotely hosting a game.) I'm sure there are better ways to do this in given particular cases (e.g. why does the server need to display the game at all?) But I've already put in a lot of work and am wondering if this method is salvageable without modifying (to much of) the underlying Game framework code I already have.

Comment: The problem is, technically, the graphics isn't been painted via the paint/print methods, but directly to the graphics device, what you need to do, is instead of painting to the BufferStrategy, you need to paint to your BufferedImage instead. Remember, you've sercumvented the normal paint processing in favour of the BufferStratgey

Comment: @MadProgrammer That's what I figured, but won't storing another BufferedImage, painting to that, then copying that to the BufferStrategy slow everything down? It kind of defeats the purpose of using a BufferStrategy right?

Comment: Since you're rendering on the server, a `BufferStrategy` seems overkill anyway, as you don't really need to care about the hard ware rendering, just make as many images as you need when you need

Comment: @MadProgrammer I agree that it's overkill, but it's built on an already existing framework. I'm comfortable going in to change the buffer strategy, but it would change it for everything, not just the server program. So I'm still concerned with speed.

Comment: Speed wise, will depend on what you are painting, if you're painting a single image, it should be fast.  You could change it so that the `BufferedImage` is painted to first and then this is painted to the `BufferStrategy`, so your own drawing the image, not all the individual elements

Comment: @MadProgrammer I would of course only draw each element once and at most be drawing a large BufferedImage to the BufferStrategy, but there are a few problems with this approach. (1) I might need to keep resizing the BufferedImage as the Canvas changes size, adding time due to heap allocation. (2) By drawing to a BufferedImage first I might as well not be using a BufferStrategy, right? (3) This would require a change to the framework I've already built, which may or may not be acceptable (generality). (4) I don't need to capture every frame, only ever frame per server "tick". (Slower then FPS.)

Comment: I would say point to is generally valid, but, BufferStrategy offers greater hardware integration. Unless you can find away to inject the painting of the BufferedImage into the existing framework in some way, I don't see you have a choice. You can also make decisions if you need to render the frame or not, discarding the use of the BufferedImage.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I wish there was a way to implement my own 'BufferStrategy' class so that I could avoid changing the underlying code; instead just change the Canvas's strategy to my custom one that writes to a BufferedImage... (Anyone know if something like that is possible?)

Comment: You could write a proxy, which would allow you to lay in between your framework and the Canvas BufferStrategy, but a better solution might be to alter the way the framework works to allow a greater deal of abstraction and pluggable code ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yea, something like a generate/get next Graphics(2D) in my Canvas class. By default it uses the current buffer strategy to get the Graphics2D, but it could be overridden. However, my server doesn't override my Canvas, it wraps one. This way I can use different subclasses of my canvas with more functionality; (I need this ability.) So my Canvas might need a setGraphicsGenerator method that accepts some functional interface perhaps. Thanks for the help with brainstorming. (Let me know if you want to see the code. It's was just to much to post here.)

Comment: I would go one step further, I would create a "renderer" interface, which you main loop would call, but doesn't care what it is, as an idea